# How to make schema dumps comparable between Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql

I have two systems running, one on linux and the other on windows. From the linux box, I ran pg_dump against both systems and dumped the schema.

pg_dump command:

```
pg_dump -h HOST -U USER -s -f /tmp/out.sql DB_NAME
```

After I removed all of the "--" comments, I diffed the files together.

Diff output snippet, linux compared to windows:

```
-    ADD CONSTRAINT sys_c004775 FOREIGN KEY (ruleid) REFERENCES rule(ruleid);
+    ADD CONSTRAINT sys_c004775 FOREIGN KEY (ruleid) REFERENCES "rule"(ruleid);
```

The linux dump does not quote any entities and windows does. Is this a function of some encoding or just of a difference between windows and linux? Is there an option in pg_dump to make the output more consistent?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather strange but both lines are correct and will work in any PostgreSQL-database on any OS. "rule" isn't a reserved word, but it is an object type in PostgreSQL. That might be the reason why some version of pg_dump treats this name different. If you realy need unquoted names, just use another name, a name without any conflicts with object types what so ever.

Comment: This isn't much help since I can't change anything about the schema. The databases are not the same version, 8.4.3 on linux, 8.2 on windows. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: And did you use the same pg_dump-version to create the backups? pg_dump version 8.4 can also create backups of an 8.2-database. Using different databases is asking for trouble, an 8.4-backup might not work in a 8.2-databaseserver. Be careful!